# What is the legal term for funds that are not fund-of-funds?

Tags: terminology, legalese, finance

I am looking for the legally correct expression for funds that are not fund-of-funds. Those funds do not invest in other funds but to at least 90% directly in stocks or bonds.

In German there is the expression "Zielfonds" which would be "target fund" in English - which is not correct as I assume. I looked through law texts in Enlish and I did not find a specific expression for this and I wonder whether it exists.

Maybe the right word is just "fund" and fund-of-funds for a distinction?

Comment: Your last sentence is correct.  They are just called *funds*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you are looking for is "[fund](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/investment-fund.asp?ad=dirN&qo=serpSearchTopBox&qsrc=1&o=40186)".

[What is a 'Fund Of Funds](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/f/fundsoffunds.asp)':

> - A fund of funds (FOF) - also referred to as a multi-manager investment - is an investment strategy in which ***a fund invests in other types of funds***. This strategy invests in a portfolio that contains different underlying assets instead of investing directly in bonds, stocks and other types of securities.

(www.investopedia.com):

Comment: thanks, I've been on investopedia.com (among other pages) too. Such texts were the reason for my conjecture.